# C: error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union OR error: '*list' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?

Tags: c, linked-list

For my linked list, I have the following:

```
typedef struct node {
  char * value;
  struct node *next;
} NODE;

void delete_nth(NODE **list, int n){
NODE *cur = *list;
int i;                    
if (n == 0){
    printf("\n==========\n");
    list = list->next;
    cur->next = NULL;
    free(cur);
} else {
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
return ;
}
```

But it returns these errors:

```
error: '*list' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?

error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You treat `list` as `NODE*`...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where the code says `list = list->next;`, what effect do you want that to have? (Hint: when you wrote `void delete_nth(NODE **list, int n){`, why did you choose `NODE**` rather than `NODE*` for `list`?) "What am I doing wrong here?" The main thing you are doing wrong is not carefully [tracing through the logic of your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) before posting. It would also be better to [show a complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) - including the line number, any highlighting etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is NODE **. NODE ** becomes struct node ** which means pointer to pointer to struct node.

The following two lines from your program are not correct:

```
void delete_nth(NODE **list, int n){
NODE *cur = *list;
```

These lines should be changed to:

```
void delete_nth(NODE *list, int n){
NODE *cur = list;
```

So, now `NODE **list` is changed to `NODE *list` and `NODE *cur = *list` is changed to `NODE *cur = list`.

Comment: But what happens if `n == 0`? How does the calling function know that the head node was removed? (Your answer may fix the compiler error, but OP's function has other issues. Passing in a reference to the head node was a good decision, but OP didn't know how to take it from there.)

Answer (score 0):

This line is not correct:

```c
    list = list->next;
```

`list` does not point to a struct but to a pointer to struct.
Also you don't want to update `list` but where `list` points to.

This would be

```c
    *list = (*list)->next;
```

If you change `list`, the calling function would not see it as it is only a copy of the passed value.

Besides this, you forgot to actually remove the nth element after iterating through your list. But that is another topic...